# QNX process profiling

Tags: multithreading, scheduling, scheduler, status, qnx-neutrino

I was wondering if there is something equivalent to Linux's /proc/PID/status for QNX Neutrino to do some program profiling. I tried ps but when it comes to 'psched' or 'state' it complains "unrecognized field name".

Answer (score 1):

OK, apparently `ps` was/is just insufficiently implemented, i.e. it is recommended to use `pidin` instead which provides similar status checking features. (Thx Mitchell Schoenbrun)